# how to parse a string for excluding special characters with regex

Tags: regex

I have one string for ex. "Drive C: Disk Usage".
Everything after the ":" is a text I want to extract with regex.
(here, its "Disk Usage") 
I am parsing it with this regex:
 `:[^:].*` 
but it considers ":" as well which i don't want .
How can I change my regular expression so that it will match any text  after ":" 
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a positive lookbehind,

```
(?<=:).*
```

It matches all  the characters which are just after to  `:`.

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=)` Positive lookbehind.
- `.*`  Matches any character(*except a newline character*) zero or more times.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rD3vT7)

**OR**

```
:\K[^:].*
```

**Explanation:**

- `:` A literal `:`
- `\K` Used to discard previously matched characters.(ie; `:`)
- `.*`  Any character(*except a newline character*) zero or more times.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oI2yB8)

Comment: +1 Yeah, that works. How about giving her a couple more options—I know you know them :) See you tomorrow, Avinash!

Comment: Hey Avinash, do you still have that chat room from the other day? I'd like to chat. :) Lost the address.

Comment: @zx81 yep sure. could you get into this http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11833/room-for-avinash-raj-and-whoever-wants-to-make-company

Comment: What If I want to extract all the text except ":" then?

Comment: you could use this `([^:]*):(.*)` regex to capture text before and after `:`. Take a look at http://regex101.com/r/tK4cB6

Answer (score -1):

Some options

Positive lookbehind

```
(?<=:).*
```

Negative ( this should be faster )

```
[^:]*$
```

Matches everything after a : , it's after because we are using the end delimiter.